# Repeat alarm daily error

Tags: android, notifications, calendar, alarmmanager

I have a problem with AlarmManager in Android. I need to repeat an alarm at 9:00 AM every day, for this i have the next code:

Main Activity on Create

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setAlarm();
}
```

setAlarm method

```
private void setAlarm() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    Intent receiver = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, receiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

}
```

AlarmReceiver

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

int MID;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("title")
            .setContentText("example").setSound(alarmSound)
            .setAutoCancel(true).setWhen(when)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
    notificationManager.notify(MID, mNotifyBuilder.build());
    MID++;

}
```

}

With this code, alarm works every day at 9.00 AM but my problem is, when I open the app the notification appears. All the time that i open the app occurs.

If the app is closed, and wait to 9.00 AM, appears notification too.

I want ONLY appears at 9.00 AM every day, not every time that i open the app.

How I can do?

Thank u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the alarm for the next 9am

```
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
if(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR) >= 9){
   calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)
}

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

Comment: @Traif, inside the if try to use HOUR_OF_DAY instead of HOUR

Comment: Cool, glad that it helped, please also upvote the answer. Thanks